# Realm crashing on inverse relationship within MKAnnotation

Tags: swift, realm, mkmapview, mkannotation

The goal is to obtain inverse relationship properties on `MKAnnotation's` title and subtitle.

I have a `MainObject` which has relationship property to `Location` object:

```
class MainObject: Object, StaticMappable {
    @objc dynamic var location: Location?
    @objc dynamic var name: String        = ""
```

The linked `Location` object has inverse relationship back to `MainObject`

```
class Location: Object, StaticMappable {
    @objc dynamic var latitude: Double  = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var longitude: Double = 0.0

    let mainObjects = LinkingObjects(fromType: MainObject.self, property: "location")
    var mainObject: MainObject? { return mainObjects.first }
```

The problem is that `Location` object also conforms to `MKAnnotation` (so I could easily display the object on the mapView)

```
extension Location: MKAnnotation {
    // coordinate already set
    // set other optional vars
    public var title: String? { return mainObject?.name }
}
```

The collection of `MainObject` is fetched on the main thread (`com.apple.main-thread (serial)`) but when the `Location` is displayed on the map the `MKAnnotation` is processed on the background thread (`com.apple.vectorkit.dispatch.layoutqueue`) and this causes the obvious crash: `Realm accessed from incorrect thread`.

`MKAnnotation` title and subtitle are get-only so I cannot set them on the main thread when I am creating the annotations.

Is there anything I can do about this?

Comment: What about doing `public var title: String? { DispatchQueue.main.async{return mainObject?.name} }`?

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I've already tried that but you need to return synchronously from the property getter or provide the value out of the async thread. In other words to be able to compile this you need to write:

`public var title: String? { DispatchQueue.main.async{return mainObject?.name} return nil }`. Which returns nil because it is the first value it finds.

Comment: Right, so what about changing `async` to `sync`? It shouldn't be used in production, since it can really slow the UI down when you have a lot of annotations, but I'm curious whether it would work or not.

Comment: Ok, I've given a try to `return DispatchQueue.main.sync{
            return " \(mainObject!.name) "
        }` but it just completely froze the map UI. No crash, just frozen.